# SQL relationship accessible via two properties and how to enforce this relationship when inserting data

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, constraints, asp.net-core-webapi, circular-dependency

I have a SQL database that I have modelled by EF Core code first approach. The problem I'm facing is related to only a small part of that model, so I will isolate it and try to explain the issue with a contrived example consisting of a small set of objects/tables and their relations.

**Setup**

Disclaimer: *This example may not make 100% sense in the real world, especially the relationship between the car size and car make tables, but it does replicate the relationship between the objects in my actual application.*

Say I have a set of quite simple objects in C# (and corresponding tables in the database) that will be used to store (and perform CRUD operations) the *cost* of applying various *technologies* that can be retrofit to a car. The car is not described by a seprate object but rather by two objects: *car make* and *car size*.

This leads to the following four objects:

```
public class Technology
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CarSize
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Make { get; set; }

    public List<CarMake> Makes { get; set; } = new List<CarMake>();
}

public class CarMake
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CarSize { get; set; }

    public string Size { get; set; }
}

public class Cost
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public int TechnologyId { get; set; }

    public int CarSizeId { get; set; }

    public List<CarMake> CarMakes { get; set; } = new List<CarMake>();

    public double Cost { get; set; }
}
```

**Use**

The idea is that a cost can be specified on different levels by referencing the different relations defined on the cost object:

1. An entry into the cost table *must* have a reference to a technology, by the `[Required]` attribute on the `TechnologyId` property on the `[Cost]` object. If this is the only reference to one of the other objects that is used, it means that this cost entry is the same for all car sizes and makes. The cost table can be filtered on the `TechnologyId` property.
2. One can alternatively also set the foreign key `CarSizeId` on the `Cost` object, which (surprisingly) means that the cost entry is valid for one particular size of cars. The cost table can be filtered on the `TechnologyId` and `CarSizeId` properties.
3. If one wants to specify that a cost of a technology retrofit is valid for a particular car size *and* a particular brand, one can both set the foreign key property `CarSizeId` and attach a `CarMake` object in the list on the cost object.

**Problem and possible solutions(?)**

And here the problem appears. In the third use case above, how can I make sure that the value for the `CarSizeId` property on the new `Cost` object being created is the same as the already existing value in the `CarSizeId` that can be found by going through the `CarMake` object?

Is there a kind of constraint that can be placed on the tables/relationship? If so, how would that be implemented in Ef Core (as I am using the code first approach).

Or is this something that in the SQL Server has to be handled in some form of script?

As in 99% of cases the data will be passed in to the database through the API, should it be the API's responsibility to check this potential inconsistency by first retrieving the `CarSize` object(s) referenced by the `Cost` object and/or the `CarMake` object and compare their id to ensure consistency?

Perhaps simply adding a validation rule that checks and sets the `CarSizeId` to `null` in case the `CarMake` property contains data?

I guess this is a well-known problem, but having much more experience with C# than SQL, this is where I hit the wall..

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I tried manually inserting into the `Cost` table and update the many-to-many relationship to the `CarSize` table via inserting a new record into the intermediate `CostCarMake` table, and without any constrains (which potentially do exist, but which I don't know how to implement) it was possible to insert the new `Cost` object with a different value for the `CarSizeId` than that which was referenced by the existing `CarMake` object referenced by the same new `Cost` object. I guess this is because the two operations don't know about each other?

Comment: I'm trying to understand your structure. Does the string `CarSize.Make` have relationship with `CarMake`? Should `int CarMake.CarSize` be `CarSizeId`? I am also confused by the terminology. It appears that a `CarMake` can only reference one `CarSize`.  In U.S. terminology, the "Make" generally refers to the manufacturer (Ford, Toyota, etc), while the term "Model" refers to the specific product (F-150, Camry). Using that terminology, a "Make" could be a variety of sizes, depending on the "Model". Are you using the terminology differently - does `CarMake` refer to what I think of as a "Model"?

Comment: Can you also post your table schemas? I am unclear how some of your class definitions would be represented in your database. In particular, `Cost` to `CarMakes` appears to be a many-to-many relationship, which would typically be implemented using a *junction table* (possibly named `CostCarMake` or `CarMakeCost`) that has FKs to both.

Comment: you could try this suggestions: Handle this validation in your application logic, specifically within the EF Core context. You can override the `SaveChanges` or `SaveChangesAsync` method in your DbContext to include custom validation logic that checks for this consistency before persisting changes to the database. As most of your data interactions happen through an API, incorporating validation logic at the API level is a viable option. This way, you can ensure that any `Cost` entity being created or updated has a `CarSizeId` that matches the `CarSizeId` in its associated `CarMake` entities.